# Python - Confusion about importing same module by two other modues

Tags: python, mongodb, python-import, pymodm

I noticed this while try to create an `flask-extension` with [pymodm](https://pymodm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html).
Consider a use case of `pymodm.MongoModel`.

## Models.py (user defined medule)

```
#line 1
from pymodm import MongoModel, fields,connect

#line 2
connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/project_matrix")

#line 3
class Model(MongoModel):
    name = fields.CharField()

#line 4
Model({"name": "test"}).save()
```

The interesting thing about `connect` method of  [connections.py](https://github.com/mongodb/pymodm/blob/master/pymodm/connection.py) module is, it uses a module level variable called `_CONNECTIONS` to store all the connections. 
After importing connect to current name space in `#line 2` We are adding a connection to `_CONNECTIONS` using connect method.

Then, in `#line 4`, we calls save method of TopLevelMongoModel class of [models.py](https://github.com/mongodb/pymodm/blob/master/pymodm/base/models.py) module which indirectly calls `collections()` of [options.py](https://github.com/mongodb/pymodm/blob/master/pymodm/base/options.py).
[options.py](https://github.com/mongodb/pymodm/blob/master/pymodm/base/options.py) imports the method `_get_db` of [connections.py](https://github.com/mongodb/pymodm/blob/master/pymodm/connection.py).

## Summery:

`Models.py` imports connect method of [connections.py](https://github.com/mongodb/pymodm/blob/master/pymodm/connection.py) to add a connection to module level variable.
[options.py](https://github.com/mongodb/pymodm/blob/master/pymodm/base/options.py) imports _get_db of [connections.py](https://github.com/mongodb/pymodm/blob/master/pymodm/connection.py) somehow managed to get a connection from `_CONNECTIONS` which is changed by `Models.py`.

What is the mechanism/concept behind this? are module level variables are global like in `JavaScript` or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. There's only one instance of `_CONNECTIONS` which is used by two other modules; why is this surprising?

Comment: well.. if a module is imported by two modules, those two modules should have two instances of `_CONNECTIONS`  not one..

Comment: But why? What makes you think that? If you assign an object to two names, you still only have one object, not two.

Comment: Is the underlying issue: why/how does Flask follow the convention of setting extension configs at the app level?

Answer (score 0):

> if a module is imported by two modules, those two modules should have two instances of _CONNECTIONS not one.

This is not so.

Your imports work that way because that's the way imports work. The `import` statement does not create a new module each time it is invoked. If the module has been previously imported, subsequent imports simply bind to the original module.

Consider these three files:

#### main.py

```
import a
import b
print(f"main, imports complete, a.x={a.x}, b.a.x={b.a.x}")
a.x = 7
print(f"modified a.x, a.x={a.x}, b.a.x={b.a.x}")
```

#### a.py

```
x = 3
print(f"Inside a, x={x}")
```

#### b.py

```
import a
print(f"Inside b, a.x={a.x}")
```

and this python3.6 session:

```
$ python3.6 main.py
Inside a, x=3
Inside b, a.x=3
main, imports complete, a.x=3, b.a.x=3
modified a.x, a.x=7, b.a.x=7
```

Notice two important things:

- The `Inside a` line is only printed once. Even though `a` is imported from both `main` and `b`, `Inside a` is only printed the first time `a` is imported. This is important: the code in `a` is only ever executed once.
- The modification to `a.x` affects both `a.x` and `b.a.x`. This is also important. There is only one `a` module, and therefore only one `a` module namespace. Anyone who imported `a` will see the same namespace with the same names and the same objects.